# Add files to an iso image and auto run a script post installation

Tags: linux, rhel

I'd like to add a tar archive in the standard Red Hat installation CD image and untar the same at a desired location using some post install scripts.

1. How do I add the tar in the iso image.
2. Where should I place the script.
3. How to link the script so that it is executed at the end of the installation process.

Comment: Can you revise the first sentence. Do you want to add the tar files **to** the iso image.

Comment: yes... i mean the same... i.e, adding some file to the .iso image of the installation cd... and then running some script post installation....

Answer (score 4):

While it's possible to rebuild a Red Hat CD ISO image, you might benefit from using the [Kickstart mechanism](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-file.html) available on existing Red Hat CDs/DVDs.

This is how I do something very similar to what you're asking.  Simply create a kickstart and add a %post section that does whatever you're planning to do.  You'll need to find a way to copy over the tar file, either by mounting an NFS share or using 'wget' to download from an HTTP server.

Comment: can u give a sample of the %post section, about how its done... i have been trying the same but not able to achieve it.

Comment: @pratap:  I'm not sure I know what you want to do.  Perhaps you want to simply download a script and run it?  An example:`wget -O somescript.sh http://mysite/somescript.sh; sh -x somescript.sh`

Comment: can u tell me if i have todo the same from cd instead of network then how this is done?